# Screw Size for Bookcase

Tags: screws

I have lost screws for a bookcase that looks like the IKEA Billy Bookcase?  The hardware store and big box stores don't have anything like it and say the screw I have is foreign.  I know it is 1.5" in length with a blunt end.  Does anyone know what kind of screw is needed?

Comment: And where to find those screws

Comment: have you lost all the screws, or can you post a photo of some.

Comment: what sort of wood is the bookcase made out of?  how big are the prepared holes?  are they going into the edge of any panels?

Answer (score 2):

If you are close to an IKEA I know that have all hardware for all there merchandise at the customer service desk for people in your situation, and it's free